# Display property name in dropdown

Tags: c#

Lets say I have this:

```
public class Languages
{
    public string Language;
    public string SpokenAbility;
    public string WrittenAbility;
}
```

Is there a way I can load this into a dropdown so that the dropdown displays the items: Language, SpokenAbility, and WrittenAbility?

Comment: Which technology are you using? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: You can use reflection to list all public members of a class.

Comment: Search for *Reflection*

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead where the keys are Language,SpokenAbility and WrittenAbility (or an enum). That's better if they are related so heavily. That makes it also more maintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// using System.Reflection;
// using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<String> properties = typeof(Languages)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(x => x.Name);
```

You can use reflection to get the properties, and LINQ to make it easier.

As Spontifixus pointed out you're using fields. all that needs to be switch is `.GetProperties` to `.GetFields`:

```
IEnumerable<String> fields = typeof(Languages)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Select(x => x.Name);
```

Extension method to make it easier:

```
public static class FieldAndPropertyExtensions
{
    /*
     * Field Methods
     */

    public static IEnumerable<String> GetFields<T>(this T obj, Boolean includeInheritedFields = true) where T : class
    {
        return getFieldsFor<T>(includeInheritedFields).Select(x => x.Name);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<String> GetFieldsFor<T>(Boolean includeInheritedFields = true) where T : class
    {
        return getFieldsFor<T>(includeInheritedFields).Select(x => x.Name);
    }
    public static IDictionary<String, Object> GetFieldValueDictionary<T>(this T obj, Boolean includeInheritedFields = true) where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = getFieldsFor<T>(includeInheritedFields);

        IDictionary<String, Object> result = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            result.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(obj));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * Property Methods
     */

    public static IEnumerable<String> GetProperties<T>(this T obj, Boolean includeInheritedProperties = true) where T : class
    {
        return getPropertiesFor<T>(includeInheritedProperties).Select(x => x.Name);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<String> GetPropertiesFor<T>(Boolean includeInheritedProperties = true) where T : class
    {
        return getPropertiesFor<T>(includeInheritedProperties).Select(x => x.Name);
    }
    public static IDictionary<String, Object> GetPropertyValueDictionary<T>(this T obj, Boolean includeInheritedProperties = true) where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = getPropertiesFor<T>(includeInheritedProperties);

        IDictionary<String, Object> result = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            result.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * Helper methods
     */
    private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> getFieldsFor<T>(Boolean includeInheritedFields = true) where T : class
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => includeInheritedFields || x.DeclaringType == typeof(T));
    }
    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> getPropertiesFor<T>(Boolean includeInheritedFields = true) where T : class
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => includeInheritedFields || x.DeclaringType == typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
// instance methods:
var languages = new Languages();
var properties = languages.GetProperties(); // prop1,prop2,prop3
var fields = languages.GetFields(); // field1,field2,field3

var propAndValue = languages.GetPropertyValueDictionary(); // Dict<propertyName,value>
var fieldAndValue = languages.GetFieldValueDictionary(); // Dict<fieldName,value>

// non-instance methods:
var properties = ObjectExtensions.GetPropertiesFor<Languages>(); // prop1,prop2,prop3
var fields = ObjectExtensions.GetFieldsFor<Languages>(); // field1,field2,field3
```

Comment: Was just about the post the same thing, guess I'll just upvote instead.

Comment: Won't work for the class as defined in the question as there are no properties, but fields.

Comment: This looks promising... how do I bind the datasource then?

Comment: @Spontifixus: Oops, good catch. Just need to switch `.GetProperties` with `.GetFields`

Comment: @FrederikMoller: Updated answer with extension methods for both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to make sure that your class has properties. The one defined in your question are fields. To transform them into properties simply add the `get;` and `set;`-methods:

```
public class Languages
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string SpokenAbility { get; set; }
    public string WrittenAbility {get; set; }
}
```

Then you can list the properties using the following code:

```
var properties = typeof(Languages).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name)
```

To retrieve the value of a property use the following code:

```
var language = new Languages(){ Language="German" };
var result = typeof(Languages).GetProperty("Language").GetValue(language);
```